# How do I print out the number of tweets returned that were only in English by utilizing a counter method?

Tags: ruby, rest, api, twitter, rubygems

I am utilizing the twitter api in which I search for tweets that have the keyword, "Lebron" in it. I'm trying to write a loop that counts the number of tweets that are ONLY in english and contains the keyword, "Lebron". I am writing this in ruby using Atom as my text editor.

p.s - I have access to Twitter already, I'm just not displaying the full keys

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "8t4G...aa6"
  config.consumer_secret     = "tmq...bFA"
  config.access_token        = "106...OwI"
  config.access_token_secret = "LDh...VnB"
end

def tweet_count
  tweet_count.count do |e|
  e == lang: "en"
  end

client.search("Lebron -rt", result_type: "recent").take(2).each do |tweet|
  puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}: #{tweet.text}" #tweet.text
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the Twitter Ruby gem](https://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter%2FREST%2FSearch:search) states that you can use the `:lang` option to restrict the search results to any [ISO-639-1 language id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes):

```
tweet_count = client.search("Lebron", lang: "en", result_type: "recent").count
puts "Found #{tweet_count} tweets in English"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @PhelpsToussaint Great :) Remember to approve the answer if it worked for you, so others can see it too.